# Tag synonym request for servers and installation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Saw on a post someone using : [dedicated-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dedicated-server) [server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) and [servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers).
Not sure to merge the first one with the last two, but [server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) and [servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers) could be synonyms. I'm not sure we needed the server tag to be distinct from dedicated server, because as far as game and servers are concerned, we will always run on dedicated server. Other type of server could use [mutual-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutual-server) or other tags.

A second request: 
We would want to create [installation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation) and synonym it with the existent [game-installation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-installation) and [install](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install).

Comment: `server` → `servers` tag synonym complete. `install` → `game-installation` tag synonym complete. Not making a synonym for `installation` as the tag doesn't exist. Feel free to discuss the rest.

Comment: @badp can you retrieve the tag-wiki suggestion I made for `install` by any luck (not sure it is still active after synonym)? It should fit `game-installation` (or `installation` regardless)

Comment: @Bapd Nevermind, I'll tailor it better for the new tag system, as `@Jeff` stated in the blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) should be a synonym of [servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers). But [dedicated-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dedicated-server) should not, in most cases they are the same and just [servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers) should be used but there are some question where it is requred. Any questions that involve the actual server software itself or is specific to a third machine doing the hosting will need this tag.

As for the second request I can't think of any time they wouldn't be synonyms, and [installation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation) is my personal preference out of those tags.

Comment: Indeed `install` is just a shortcut for `installation`. So it should be used with priority over install. (In my opinion). On the `installation` vs `game-installation`, I'm pretty sure we don't treat `installation` that aren't `game-installation` as on-topic.